# Coinbase API not triggering notification URL

Tags: php, callback, coinbase-api

I have a Coinbase API setup with a notification URL. I know the API integration is working, because I've done some testing with listing the accounts and creating addresses. I know the notification URL is accessible, because I've tried it in the browser. However, transactions do not trigger the notification URL. I know the transactions are going through, because I can check my account history, and I'm receiving emails for them. However, even though I have this at the top of the relevant function in my controller:

```
file_put_contents(getcwd()."/assets/post.log",print_r($_POST,true));
```

Nothing has ever been logged there, aside from empty arrays when I access the notification URL in the browser. The notification URL is simply not being triggered. What possible steps can I take to troubleshoot it at this point?

Comment: Hi, are you able to find solution for this? thanks

Comment: @bumbumpaw I finally have. Try logging php://input.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log $_GET and $_SERVER too.
2. Personally I believe json_encode() is better than print_r(). Allows you to display anything in different viewers.
3. Make sure you post and pull to the URL from other IPs to make sure it is accessible.
4. Make sure you have https (from letsencrypt) in case it only pulls/posts to https?
5. Make sure you have apache/nginx access and error logs set up properly.